# Нужно внести несколько чисел, после чего выведутся только те, которые нацело делиться на 3

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Введите число"))
b = 0
while True:
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(a // 3)
    elif a == 0:
        print()
        a=+1
```

Comment: В строке может быть несколько чисел, среди которых нужно вывести только те, которые нацело делятся на 3, правильно? Если в строке всего одно число, то цикл Вам и не нужен. И в каком виде у Вас вводятся числа? Приложите пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: elif a == 0: а что это?

Answer (score 0):

Если следовать Вашей логике, то вводится одно число и его нужно проверить на делимость на 3:

```py
a = int(input("Введите число"))

if a % 3 == 0:
    print(a)
```

Если Вам в цикле нужно вводить числа и выводить делится или нет(условием выхода из цикла является введенная -1):

```py
while True:
    a = int(input("Введите число"))
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(f'Число {a} делится на 3')
    else:
        print(f'Число {a} не делится на 3')
    if a == -1:
        break
```

Если Вам нужно изначально ввести несколько чисел и потом вывести только те, что делятся(числа отделяются друг от друга пробелом):

```py
a = input("Введите числа> ")

numbers = a.split(' ')

for number in numbers:
    if number.isdigit() and int(number) % 3 == 0:
        print(number)
```